# Ruby service oriented architecture - how to ensure synchronization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-services, soa

I'm a newbie to writing service-oriented applications, so this might be a trivial question for some.

My current setup is something like this:
1 - A base rails app. Also contains the routes and some application logic.
2 - A few services. I have extracted these from my base rails app. They are mostly resources that were DB extensive or used a no-sql solution.

So, what I have ended up doing is something like this

in my rails app, I have a places controller which responds to all the basic CRUD operations on places. Internally it does a HTTP call to the places service.

```
def show
    req = Typhoeus::Request.new('http://127.0.0.1:7439/places/#{params[:id]}.json')
    @places = req.response.body
end
```

The problem is, if I make more than 1 service call, then how to make sure that I have the response for all before rendering the views ? Also, even with 1 service call, how does the Rails rendering process work ? So for example, if the service takes a long time to respond, does the page gets rendered or does it wait infinitely for the response ?

Comment: I'd advise you to use ActiveResource, would be much easier to maintain.

Comment: The docs page specifically states how to make parallel requests and wait for all to complete. https://github.com/dbalatero/typhoeus

Comment: probably this book [Service-Oriented Design with Ruby and Rails](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/book/web-development/ruby/9780321700124) is what you need

Answer (score 0):

I cannot answer your question specifically about Typhoeus as I've never used it, but I will try to answer more generally about this problem in SOA and hopefully it will be helpful.

The common thread is that the UI should be composed from many services and tolerant to the possibility that some of those services may be down or unresponsive.

You have a few options:

1) Drop down and do the composition from the browser. Use something like Backbone and make Ajax requests to each of the services. You can make many of these requests asynchronously and render each part of the page when they return - if one doesn't return, don't render that part - or have Backbone render some sort of placeholder in that region.

2) If you want to build up a model object in your controller (as in your example), you have to somehow handle timeouts and again - use a placeholder model for whatever service is being unresponsive. The nice thing about this is that, depending on the service, you can decide how critical is to have the data and how much time you're willing to wait before you consider it a timeout and move on.

Take, for example, the Amazon product page. It's very important to get the details about the product from its service - if you don't get that, it's probably worth throwing an error to the browser. But if the "Customers Who Purchased This Product Also Purchased..." service is not responding, it's OK to just stop waiting for it and render the page without it.

Again - I don't know Typhoeus so I'm not sure how to manage this using it, but hopefully this helps. Good luck!